# Running Continuous (contains while true) and pre-built class inside current class without any effects on the current running class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 classes (`Client.java`, `Continuous.java`)

I have a

> public void trig()

statement inside the `Continuous.java` class
and it contains a

> while(true){}

statement,
So the loop unbreakable ,and it is Continuous

I need to do this:

```
Continuous cs =new Continuous();
cs.trig();
```

inside the `Client.java` without any effect on the  `Client.java` Running method, In other meaning i need  the lines that become after those lines
runs without wait the `cs.trig();` to finish

Comment: You can make use of Threads in java.

Comment: @Avi can you Explain More please

Comment: @Avi with Code Please

Comment: please read about Thread and try using it.Don't expect ready made code.If you find any trouble while coding we are here to help.

Comment: @Avi 
i know that i will make the class Continuous.java
implements the Runnable interface
but my question is what is the part 
that i will put it inside the  Run() statement

Comment: If you want Continuous to run continuously you need to put `while(true){}` loop in the run method.

Comment: @Avi i've tried this before ,thanks ,but it doesnt work because the Client.java
still waiting it -_-

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Make `continuous` a `Runnable` (implement the interface) or `Thread` (extend the class), and run it as a separate thread/task from `client`.

Answer (score 0):

Have `Continuous.java` implement the `Runnable` interface. This will enforce that you implement the `run` method. From the `run` method either call your method with the `while(true)` loop or move that code to the `run` method.

Then you can run that code from `Client.java` with:

`Continuous continuous = new Continuous();
continuous.run();`

This will call the `run` method and execute on a separate thread.